# Why can I see modules downloaded inside a virtual environment outside my project folder?

Tags: python

I followed the steps here, https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/26/python-virtual-env/ , to create a virtual environment on mac. I then installed modules for my project using pip3 install, and then when I navigate outside that project directory, and I do pip3 list, why can I still see all of the modules installed while in the virtual environment?

Comment: Leaving the folder will not deactivate the virtual environment. You have to use the `deacticate` command.

Comment: so i can’t have multiple virtual environments running at the same time? and if i were to deactivate it then my already existing modules would be there right?

Comment: You can have multiple active, but not on the same terminal.